# how to use javascript to get the position of highlighted words in a html

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use Javascript to get the position of highlighted words in an HTML file?

Comment: How are the words highlighted? What do you mean by "position" exactly?

Comment: Yes, your question needs a lot of explaining.

Comment: Even if he means "selected", what does he mean with "position"? Position relative to the window, document...?

Comment: Do you mean position or index in a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into `window.getSelection`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/selection

This is for Firefox though.

You will need to do research to make it cross-browser.

Maybe there is a open-source library that does this.

Comment: Rangy's a great library! There are lots of quirks when coding with selection and text ranges across browsers, so it will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) (http://code.google.com/p/rangy).

> A cross-browser JavaScript range and selection library. It provides a simple standards-based API for performing common DOM Range and Selection tasks in all major browsers, abstracting away the wildly different implementations of this functionality between Internet Explorer and DOM-compliant browsers.

(Disclaimer: This answer is promoting the comment from the author that library to an answer, where it belongs)

Comment: Does it provide the function to select the neighbors of the highlighted words? Sometimes users only select one word, but it'll be helpful to locate the word if we get the neighbors of it.